# How rails resolve multi-requests at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Prepare for the test:**
`sleep 10` in a action

**Test:**
Open two tabs in the browser to visit the action

**Result:**
When the second request is running, the first request finished and began rendering the view, but the view is still blank.
After the second request finished too, the two requests finished rendering the view at the same time.

**Conclusion:**
Rails is just one single instance. One request can only enter the action after the previous requests finish. But how to explain the response part? Why the multi-requests finish rendering the views at the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using a  `WEBrick` server? That must be because your server is a single threaded server and is capable of fulfilling one request at a time (because of the single worker thread). Now in case of multiple requests, it runs the action part of the request and before running the view renderer it checks to see if there are any pending requests. Now if 10 requests are lined up, it would first complete all of them before actually rendering the views. When all of these requests are completed, the views would now be rendered sequentially.

You can switch to Passenger or Unicorn server if you want multi-threaded environment.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: thanks, you make me less confused. I test with more requests at the same time, it seems that after less than 10 requests are lined up, webrick will render the views and then resolve other requests.

Comment: I think webrick is not a single threaded server, you can set 'config.threadsafe!' in production.rb, then it will resolve multi-requests at the same time.

Comment: `config.threadsafe!` won't automatically make WEBrick multi-threaded. See my answer for details.

Comment: This answer isn't entirely correct. Instead of doing the check before just rendering the view, Rails puts a lock around the whole request which includes processing the request and generating the response, thanks to Rack::Lock. Also Passenger or Unicorn won't spawn threads. They spawn workers which run as separate processes.

Answer (score 25):

WEBrick is multi-threaded but Rails developers hard-coded a mutex, so it can handle just one request at a time. You can monkey-patch `Rails::Server` and you are free to run a multi-threaded WEBrick.

Just note that WEBrick will be multithreaded only when config `config.cache_classes = true` and `config.eager_load = true`, which is typical to `RAILS_ENV=production`. This is because class reloading in development is not thread safe.

To get WEBrick fully multi-threaded in Rails 4.0, just add this to `config/initializers/multithreaded_webrick.rb`:

```
# Remove Rack::Lock so WEBrick can be fully multi-threaded.
require 'rails/commands/server'

class Rails::Server
  def middleware
    middlewares = []
    middlewares << [Rails::Rack::Debugger] if options[:debugger]
    middlewares << [::Rack::ContentLength]

    Hash.new middlewares
  end
end
```

The offending code in `rails/commands/server.rb` that we got rid of is:

```
# FIXME: add Rack::Lock in the case people are using webrick.
# This is to remain backwards compatible for those who are
# running webrick in production. We should consider removing this
# in development.
if server.name == 'Rack::Handler::WEBrick'
  middlewares << [::Rack::Lock]
end
```

It's not needed on Rails 4.2. It's concurrent out-of-the-box.

Comment: Added, but still adds `Rack::Lock` to middleware

Comment: @geekazoid, Rails 4.1 I assume? I tested it on Rails 4.0 only. I will see how to do it in 4.1.

Comment: Is it solved adding `config.allow_concurrency=true`?

Comment: Rails 4.2 is concurrent in `RAILS_ENV=production` out of the box.

Comment: Hi @Nowaker, what is required for 4.1? Does it also work out of the box or should we use the workaround above?

Comment: @Matt, I don't have any Rails 4.1 app by hand. Can you please check yourself and let me know?

Comment: Or simply add `config.middleware.delete 'Rack::Lock'` in your application.rb

Comment: Nice, the initializer resolves the issue in Rails 4.2, I wrapped it in "unless Rails.env.production?" condition to execute only in test and development. Other suggestions like 'config.middleware.delete ...' or 'config.allow_concurrency...' DID NOT help

Comment: Ok but Rack::Lock was also included as a middleware in Rails 3. But Rails 3's WEBrick was able to handle multiple requests at one time. See what's in Rails 3: Rails.application.config.middleware
=> #<ActionDispatch::MiddlewareStack:0x007fb759b1b238
 @middlewares=
  [ActionDispatch::Static,
   Rack::Lock,...

Comment: just adding the initializer on its own saved me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

under your env setup config/environments/development.rb (or in config/application.rb)

add this line :

```
  #Enable threaded mode
  config.threadsafe!
```

Comment: This option is no longer needed / supported (at least since Rails 4). For details see http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/06/18/removing-config-threadsafe.html