# Webrick crashes frequently

Tags: ruby, redmine, webrick

I use ruby 1.8.7 and redmine 2.5.0. I run the application with

```
root@administrator:/home/dax/redmine-2.5.0# ruby script/rails server webrick -d -e production
```

I get Segmentation Fault on terminal every time it crashes. Following are two of it :

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/utils.rb:422: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
```

---

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/cache/file_store.rb:139: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
```

Answer (score 0):

The version of ruby that is being used might be at fault.

From the [Rails 3.2 release notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_2_release_notes.html):

> Note that Ruby 1.8.7 p248 and p249 have marshalling bugs that crash Rails. Ruby Enterprise Edition has these fixed since the release of 1.8.7-2010.02. On the 1.9 front, Ruby 1.9.1 is not usable because it outright segfaults, so if you want to use 1.9.x, jump on to 1.9.2 or 1.9.3 for smooth sailing.

Comment: in any way, can we increase the memory allocated to webrick ?

Comment: if you are on a memory constrained system you can create a swapfile that the system uses after it runs out of the system memory. But if the problem lies in the ruby implementation, then you will probably need to switch to a version that is not affected. Is this a development machine?

Comment: on production machine

Comment: webbrick is not really designed to be a production webserver like passenger,thin,unicorn etc. [more info](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10859687/3145038)

Comment: which one do you prefer ?

Comment: For production I use passenger+nginx on ubuntu. [Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-rails-and-nginx-with-passenger-on-ubuntu) is a good guide for installing it. Are you constrained to that specific version of Ruby?